# How do I investigate a dropped php session bug that I can't replicate?

Tags: php

On one of my clients e-commerce site (my own php code adapted from oScommerce) is getting reports of "customers going to the checkout to find their basket is empty".

This would indicate either php sessions/cookies are somehow getting dropped or something is going wrong when switching to the secure server. There's nothing clever going on here, just standard html forms, some basic javascript for form validation and the php.

I have tried to reproduce this in many many ways and I've never seen the problem come up.

The customers who phone my client to say its happening never seem to have anything in common - time of day, browser, location, device type. It just seems totally random.

The overall conversion rate of the site hasn't dropped so it would see this is only happening for a tiny number of users.

My hosting company have given the server a once over and found no problems, so I'm now drawing a blank. Anyone got any suggestions on what I can test next?

Comment: Are you using the standard session mechanism or are you storing the sessions in for example a database? Could be a time-out.

Comment: I'll assume the content of the basket is generated via PHP Session. Could it be that customers have left the page and the session died.

Comment: May want to add some code on there to give each visitor a unique token that can be referenced when calling in (short but unique) that you could then use to research visitor logs and backtrace his/her steps. Maybe place it in the footer or other inconspicuous place (but easily located while on the phone).

Comment: Do you know that there's a max lifetime setting for sessions? It's controlled by php's `session.gc_maxlifetime`. Check your phpinfo.

Comment: jeroen - storing in a DB. Also got me wondering if that DB size or the data size is too big or needs sanitised (that idea from billythekid on twitter btw)

Donald - will defo check this out as a possibility too.

BradChristie - Thats a GREAT idea. Thank you.

Marek - Will do - thank you too!